# Apache CXF Service Landing Page

Tags: web-services, cxf

In other WS frameworks, when browsing to the root of the service you get a nice listing of the methods, parameters etc. My CXF service doesn't seem to allow for this. All I get is an error: "No binding operation info while invoking unknown method with params unknown."

Is there anyway to create this index.html style behaviour in CXF to browse through the service description without having to read the WSDL?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have to create an HTML content and put the WSDL treatment logic there. Then, create a REST service with @Path("/") and return this content.

Answer (score 0):

i've the same problem, after migrating from cxf war on tomcat to spring boot + cxf...
when go to the landing page no more soap method resume, the respond a soap fault in place of sending the landing page....